# How to design concurring tasks optimally

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

I have a Windows form that displays any number of records: these data sets describe objects for which calculations need to be performed.

For most data sets, these calculations can be performed without changing the objects.

While these calculations are running - I call this part of the work Process A - the objects belonging to the remaining data sets should be processed. Only then can the calculations for these remaining data sets be carried out - I call this part of the work Process B.

The calculations for A and B are carried out by instances of a different form that accesses a C++ DLL.

After the calculation of a process has been completed, a file is created for A and B respectively, the existence of which indicates the end of the calculation for this process.

Both A and B may take longer than the other processes because the amount of data sets in each can be very different. Only after both processes have ended can the results of their calculations be merged.

How can I optimally design both tasks?

I am using C# and .Net Framework 4.5.2.
To clarify:
[image: schematic]

Theodor Zoulias, thank you for your interest in my question. To explain more:
Both threads should each process a structurally identical List(Of Objects) in the form called:

```
public class ListEl : IComparable<ListEl>
{
    public string objName; //Name of the object that is the subject of calculations with the C++ DLL
    public double[] values;
}
```

The values[] to be calculated are partly dependent on each other. The calculations are performed by calling class calculations:

```
using C++-DLL;
class calculations
{
    public static int calc(ListEl s, string saveName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (C++-DLL.calc(saveName) == 1)
            {
                errorMsg = "Error!\n";
                return -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMsg = ex.Message;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public static void saveResults(ListEl s, string filename)
    {
    }
}
```

The calling form:

```
public partial class SelectObjects : Form
{
    public class ListEl : IComparable<ListEl>
    {
        public string objName;  //Name of the object that is the subject of calculations with the C++ DLL
        public double[] values; //results  of calculations with the C++ DLL
    }
    private string calling = "";
    
    public Form SelectObjects()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        listA = new List<ListEl>();
        listB = new List<ListEl>();
        
        fillListA();
        fillListB();
    }
 
    private void buttonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmCalc frmA = new FrmCalc()
        {
            listA = this.listA,
            calling = "A";
        };
        frmA.Show();
    }
 
    private void buttonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmCalc frmB = new FrmCalc()
        {
            listB = this.listB,
            calling = "B";
        };
        frmB.Show();
    }
    
    public void mergeResults()
    {
        // reading results A and B to list
    }
}
```

The form is called twice:

```
public partial class FrmCalc : Form
{
    public class ListEl : IComparable<ListEl>
    {
        public string objName;
        public double[] values;
    }
    private string _calling = "";
    public string calling
    {
        get { return _calling; }
        set { _calling = value; }
    }
       
    Threading.Thread threadA;
    Threading.Thread threadB;
    
    public FrmCalc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        listA = new List<ListEl>();
        listB = new List<ListEl>();
    }
 
    private void FrmCalc_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calling == "A")
        {
            ThreadA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(workA));
            ThreadA.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            ThreadA.Start();
        }
        else if (calling == "B")
        {
            threadB = new Thread(new ThreadStart(workB));
            threadB.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            threadB.Start();
        }
    }
    
    public void workA()
    {
        foreach (ListEl s in listA)
        {
            calculations.calc(s, saveName);
            calculations.saveResults(s, fileResultsA);
        }
    }
    
    public void workB()
    {
        foreach (ListEl s in listB)
        {
            calculations.calc(s, saveName);
            calculations.saveResults(s, fileResultsB);
        }
    }
}
```

If FrmCalc is called twice as shown here, the calculations in the C++ DLL class inevitably lead to conflicts. How can we prevent this?
Perhaps by calling two copies of the C++ DLL in class calculations?